# Should the lid be closed when boiling masala tea?

Tags: tea

I guess with the lid closed, tea boiling is faster, but will it have an adverse impact on the taste of the tea?

Comment: AFAIK, it should not impact the taste, but can you share the recipe or technique , maybe there's something we're missing to fully answer the question?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  We need to know more to help you, though.  For example: are you boiling plain water, water with just tea, water with tea, sugar and spices, or even milk?  It makes a difference.